# How to report data from a SQL Server using Qlikview

Tags: sql-server, qlikview

I would like to know if anyone of you can help me with reporting data from a SQL Server 2005 Enterprise ed. using qlikview and having the data refreshed constantly directly from the database visually using charts.

Many thanks.

Regards,
Tunde

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, this is possible, what exactly are you searching for?
QlikView would use an ODBC or OLEDB connection to SQL-Server and then you can use all the functionality QlikView provides.